# How do I fade-in all p tag contents in the page one by one with some time interval using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fade-in all the p tag contents onload with some interval one by one, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>  <body>  <p>1</p>  <p>2</p>  <p>3</p>  <p>4</p>  <p>5</p>  <p>6</p>  </body>  </html>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
     var len = $('#nav li').length,  cnt = 0;  
     $('#change').click(function ()  { 
         if (cnt < len)  { $('#nav li:eq('+cnt+')').css('color', '#F00');  cnt++;  } 
         else {  alert("all li text color changed!"); } 
     }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
html p {display:none;}
```

[here is my code check it](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/jm86Z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
(function fadeNext(jq){
    jq.eq(0).fadeIn("slow", function(){
        // you can also set a timeout here if you'd like
        (jq=jq.slice(1)).length && fadeNext(jq);
    });
})($('#content p'))
```

It's based on this post: http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/